# Is there a rotation of a regular hexagon where the width measured from the center is equal to the length measured from the center?

Tags: geometry

If you were to measure a regular hexagon, is there a way to rotate the hexagon so that if there were two lines bisecting the center of the hexagon, both lines would be the same length? Can we then use the lengths of those lines to determine the area of the hexagon?

Edit: To clarify, I mean that I intend for the lines to be perpendicular.

Comment: Am I correct that your use of "width" and "length" in the title means that you intend these lines to be perpendicular? ... In any case: Yes, it's certainly possible to find lines of equal length: simply rotate the hexagon so that a vertex lies on a bisector of an angle formed by the lines. (Finding the corresponding area is left as an exercise to the reader.)

Comment: The center of a hexagon is a point, you can't bisect that. But I think you mean what @Blue has already addresses.

Comment: The answer is yes for a wide variety of (convex) shapes if you rotate the figure about a given point. Continuity means that if the difference of the distance to the circumference on two lines from the point at some angle of rotation is positive, and at another angle of rotation is negative, there will be an angle in between where it is zero.

Comment: Choose any line of symmetry of the hexagon, and rotate until that line is at 45 degrees to the two perpendicular lines.